# How to echo shell commands and comments as they are executed

Tags: shell

I want to print almost all commands and all comments. Is there a way to do that? as below:

```sh
$ cat shl
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
set -x
# this is my bash script.
DIR=/tmp/so
ls $DIR
```

```sh
$ bash shl 
+ #!/bin/bash 
+ # this is my bash script.
+ DIR=/tmp/so
+ ls /tmp/so
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this and the commands as well as the comments will be printed as executed:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv                                                                     
# this is my bash script.
DIR=/tmp/so
ls $DIR
```

Comment: The `-v` shows the line that is about to be parsed; the `-x` shows the line as it was parsed before being executed. I think. You can also `set -vx` to turn these on and `set +vx` to turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

Write your comments as arguments to a no-op command. (:)

```
$ cat shl
#!/bin/bash -x
: this is my bash script.
DIR=/tmp/so
ls $DIR
```

output:

```
$ ./shl
+ : this is my bash script.
+ DIR=/tmp/so
+ ls /tmp/so
```

Comment: I do this a lot, but it doesn't show actual *comments*.